# IE11 - layout issues when zoomed out to 50%

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, zooming, zurb-foundation

A couple websites we've developed with Zurb Foundation 4 & 5 exhibit a strange (edge case) behaviour when zoomed out to varying levels on IE11.  For example, with [one website](http://www.SandhurstHandTherapy.com.au/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=ie11zoomoutissue) when zoomed out < 63% on IE11 (window maximised IE11/Win7 running on VMWare Fusion on 1440w screen; mileage may vary so zoom out less than 50% to be more likely to see the behaviour), the main content div moves off center.  The threshold at which the block goes off center seems to have some relation with the zoom level vs window width.

**Normal Layout:**
[image: Website zoomed out on Safari/OSX - proper layout]

**Exhibiting layout issue on IE11 when zoomed out:**
[image: Website zoomed out on IE11/Win7 exhibiting off center div layout issue]

The sites have been tested across a variety of devices and browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, iOS Safari, Android Chrome, Android FF) and all render properly and zoom out with no problems.  It is interesting to note that zooming out to similar levels doesn't break the layout even on IE8.

Is this a strange IE11 bug?  I consider it a bit of an edge case because I'd wouldn't imagine many would regularly zoom out to that degree, but it's a bit of a curiosity because it doesn't occur on IE8 and I've only observed it on Foundation 4+ sites.

Comment: I would guess that this is either an IE11 bug, or that there are some IE-specific styles that's causing it.  Use the [F12 Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg589507(VS.85).aspx) to see what's actually going on.

Comment: Yes had quite a thorough look using IE Developer tools. Can't quite tell what happens at the threshold.  The div is centered using margin-left / margin-right: auto, but at beyond the threshold, the 'offset' in layout metrics appears to change.  Haven't been able to track down why...

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look in IE11 and can duplicate the issue when I zoom out to 50%.

`div#contentContainer` has `max-width` set to `62.5rem`. Change the value to `100rem` and the panel will center-align appropriately to the screen.

You may want to consider switching from a `rem` value to `em`.

Comment: Foundation 5 grid uses rem sizing.  Foundation 4 uses em sizing, but some sites using F4 still exhibit the behaviour so I'm not sure that changing to em will solve the issue.

Comment: As long as you change 62.5 to 100 then either unit of measure should fix the issue.